# how to create controllers for objects with a one to many relationship with JPA?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jpa

If I have two beans, one for a team and another for players. A team cannot exist without players and a player must belong to a team. If my two beans are declared basically how they are below (assuming the getters and setters exist). If Im following an MVC design pattern, whats the best practice for designing the controllers, or managed beans to persist these objects to the database? The web from would ask for the name of the team and the players names AT THE SAME TIME upon submitting. Do I need two managed beans, one for player and one for team? or do I just need one managed bean for a team because a team owns players?

```
@Entity
@Table(name = 'teams')
public class Team {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Integer id;

  private String name;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy='team', cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
  private List<Player> players = new ArrayList<Player>();
}

@Entity
@Table(name = 'players')
public class Player {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Integer id;

  private String lastname;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = 'team_id')
  private Team team;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would group it in the controller by functionality, not by entity bean. So, one controller is enough.

Choosing the name has always been one of the trickiest parts of programming :) You could go with `TeamController` or `PlayerController`, see what fits better.

Answer (score 0):

for me create just a new managed bean like this

```
public class TeamBean {
     public String nameTeam;
     public list<String> namePlayer;
     // getter & setter
```

in your jsp

```
<input .. name="nameTeam"> //team name
// the important is the attribute name must be the same as your managedbean
<input .. name="namePlayer"> //player 1 name
<input .. name="namePlayer"> //player 2 name
```

....

your controller like this

```
@Controller
public class YourController {
    ....

    @RequestMapping(...) 
    public String save-team(@ModelAttribute TeamBean teamBean , HttpServletRequest request) {
        // now you have the object teamBean you can persist it in your db
        // for example
        Team team = yourTeamDAO.save(new Team(teamBean.nameTeam))
        for(Player p : teamBean.namePlayer){
             yourPlayerDAO.save(new Player(p,team))    
        }
        //just declare in your entities the constructors that i have used `new Player(...)` , `new Team(..)`
    }
```